# How to split a string into small chunks of fixed length in C to send from Arduino BLE?

Tags: c, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to send a long String data from my Arduino BLE program to my android app. How I can split my long string into chunks of 20 bytes to send to the app.

```
char data[] = "lat:29.459612,lon:44.011856,speed:0.75,sats:9";
char sendBuffer[20];
int len = sizeof(data);
int buflen= sizeof(sendBuffer);
int i = 0;
for (i=buflen; i<len+buflen; i=i+buflen) {
  memcpy(sendBuffer,data,i);
  *data= *data+i;
  ble.print("AT+BLEUARTTX=");
  ble.println(sendBuffer);
  delay(10000);
}
```

But I am not getting the expected result. Thank you for any help!

Comment: I'm not surprised your not getting the results you seek (whatever those are). Your code invokes *undefined behavior*. You `memcpy` size argument is too large. Your `*data` increment make no sense. You need an iterating pointer for the latter, and proper math for the former. I admit I don't know the first thing about the `println` member of `ble`, but if it requires a terminated string, that's missing as well.

Comment: your sendBuffer is not null terminated after memcpy.

Comment: @WhozCraig,@vivek thanks for the reply. Can you please suggest me any corrections or kindly point me any examples of  the same in c , so that i will get the correct idea. Thanks

Comment: There are so many errors... sendBuffer not being null terminated, memcpy `i` characters, when it should be `buflen`, not considering if len is an exact multiple of `buflen`, using `*data= *data+i` to advance a pointer (this is really terrible)

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not knowing the first thing about Arduino and BLE, I can only offer assistance with the actual math you're doing, which is wrong.

First some minor points:

```
char data[] = "lat:29.459612,lon:44.011856,speed:0.75,sats:9";
char sendBuffer[20];

int len = sizeof(data); // HERE
int buflen= sizeof(sendBuffer); // HERE
```

Both of those should be `size_t` type. Apart from that, unless you're planning on sending the terminating nullchar character of your string, the actual data size of your send should be one-less than what you have now, which you can get via simple subtraction or via `strlen`.

Beyond that, this is completely wrong:

```
for( i=buflen; i<len+buflen; i=i+buflen){
    memcpy(sendBuffer,data,i);
    *data= *data+i;
    ble.print("AT+BLEUARTTX=");
    ble.println(sendBuffer);
    delay(10000);
}
```

The string you're sending is 45 characters. This loop starts at 20. Therefore, the first iteration of your `memcpy` will do this:

```
memcpy(sendBuffer, data, 20);
```

However, the *second* iteration will do this:

```
memcpy(sendBuffer, data, 40);
```

The third:

```
memcpy(sendBuffer, data, 60);
```

but by that time you're long since invoked undefined behavior.

Further, your attempt to increment your source buffer starting location using pointer math is wrong, and looks like you tried to "fix" the problem of modifying a non-lvalue. i.e. It looks like you first tried this:

```
data = data + i;
```

and when that didn't work, you shoved `*` in front of each `data`, it compiled, so you ran with it. Believe me. C is *not* a language you want throw at a wall to see if something sticks.

Finally, I highly suspect your `println` member requires a nulchar terminated string, which you're not providing.

---

The following code addresses all of the above. It just dumps to a console. You'll have to tailor it for your needs regarding sending it... wherever.

**Example**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char data[] = "lat:29.459612,lon:44.011856,speed:0.75,sats:9";
    char buffer[21] = {0}; // note space for terminator

    size_t len = strlen(data);      // doesn't count terminator
    size_t blen = sizeof(buffer)-1; // doesn't count terminator
    size_t i = 0;

    // put up a header row so you can see the output in columns
    for (i=0; i<blen; ++i)
        printf("%zu", i%10);
    fputc('\n', stdout);

    // the actual loop that enumerates your buffer
    for (i=0; i<len/blen; ++i)
    {
        memcpy(buffer, data + (i*blen), blen);
        puts(buffer);
    }

    // if there is anything left over
    if (len % blen)
        puts(data + (len - len % blen));

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
01234567890123456789
lat:29.459612,lon:44
.011856,speed:0.75,s
ats:9
```

Note we never overwrite the 21'st char in that send-buffer, which was initialized to 0's, so it is always terminated. Also we pick up the short frame (if there is one) directly from the source string as the last operation.

I leave integrating the actual send logic to you.

Comment: What a patience you have, man, +1

Comment: @WhozCraig, Antonio: Thank you , now i got the idea precisely and i'll change your example to suit my needs. Thank you.

Comment: @proCoder Glad it helped.